# How to transform a dictionary into a list in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I need to transform this JSON in Python3:

```
data = [
      {
      'table_name': 'Table',
      'columns': [
        {
          'column_name': 'column_1',
          'values': [{'value': 'data1_c1', 'other':25}, {'value': 'data2_c1', other:25}]
        },
        {
          'column_name': 'column_2',
          'values': [{'value': 'data1_c2', other:30}, {'value': 'data2_c2', other:30}]
        },
        {
          'column_name': 'column_3',
          'values': [{'value': 'data1_c3', other:40}, {'value': 'data2_c3', other:40}]
        }
      ]
     }
  ]
```

to this list:

```
result = [['data1_c1, 'data2_c1'], ['data1_c2, 'data2_c2'], ['data1_c3, 'data2_c3']]
```

I was trying with this:

```
result = []
data_list = data[0]['columns']

for i in data_list:
    for j in i['values']:
        result.append([j['value']])
```

I want to get this list and then transform it into a numpy array.

Comment: So what did the code you've posted do? How did that differ from your expectations of it?

Comment: `np.array(result)` is a (6,1) array.  You'd get the desired result with a `reshape(3,2)`.  You could be more creative in the `j` loop, collecting `value` in to a new list, but if the final goal is a numpy array, reshaping is easy.

Comment: If you'd posted `result`, and discussed why it didn't meet your needs, the solution might have become obvious. Oh, and your `data` was missing quotes on a bunch of `other`, making a copy-n-paste more tedious.  And, this isn't a problem with transforming A dictionary, it's dealing with several levels of dicitonary and list nesting.  You only want one value from each dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
[[j['value'] for j in i['values']] for i in data[0]['columns']]
#[['data1_c1', 'data2_c1'], ['data1_c2', 'data2_c2'], ['data1_c3', 'data2_c3']]
```

Answer (score 0):

here is code.

```
data = [
      {
      'table_name': 'Table',
      'columns': [
        {
          'column_name': 'column_1',
          'values': [{'value': 'data1_c1', 'other':25}, {'value': 'data2_c1', 'other':25}]
        },
        {
          'column_name': 'column_2',
          'values': [{'value': 'data1_c2', 'other':30}, {'value': 'data2_c2', 'other':30}]
        },
        {
          'column_name': 'column_3',
          'values': [{'value': 'data1_c3', 'other':40}, {'value': 'data2_c3', 'other':40}]
        }
      ]
     }
  ]

result = []
data_list = data[0]['columns']

for i in data_list:
    inner_list = []
    for j in i['values']:
        inner_list.append(j['value'])
    result.append(inner_list)


print(result)
```